# DrupalChat AJAX moderation

Tags: ajax

I'm using [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module.

I've set AJAX polling, but I can't delete any messages as moderator. Is there any solution to enable chat moderation?

Comment: What do you mean by "moderate" and "clean"?

Comment: Deleting messages for example.

Comment: Rather than "for example", please edit your question and be very specific about what you're asking. It's hard to see how you're going to get any sort of useful answer with the question as it currently is